# is there any css validator with CSS3 and vendor specific extensions support?

Tags: css, validation, xhtml, w3c

is there any css validator with CSS3 and vendor specific extensions support?

I only want to see problem other than CSS 3 and vendor specific extensions related errors.

And is there any better xhtml css validator than W3C's?

Comment: You can't expect standard-proofing tools to validate non-standard properties like vendor-specific extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select "CSS Level 3" in the More options>Profile section of the [W3C CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

[image: CSS3]

Although this won't help with the vendor-specific errors. [It looks like there is no intention to support these in the W3C validator](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2007Jan/0032.html).

Answer (score 1):

The W3C Validator unfortunately goes crazy over CSS3.
This one may work for you [CSS3 Validator](http://validator.nu/)