# Are there any CSS validators besides jigsaw?

Tags: css, validation, w3c-validation

Are there any other CSS validation sites out there besides [jigsaw](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

It’s saying that `content: none;` is incorrect, but according to the specs it should be fine.

Comment: The validator says you're wrong, so you're looking for another validator, eh? There's the ticket...

Comment: The W3C's validators are great, but they aren't bug free (see http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/buglist.cgi?product=CSSValidator). Sometimes a CSS document will validate against an old version of the validator but not the current one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any css validator with CSS3 and vendor specific extensions support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706993/is-there-any-css-validator-with-css3-and-vendor-specific-extensions-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best online css validator that I have found is http://www.w3schools.com/site/site_validate.asp

There are also good browser plug-ins that you can use to validate your css. I recently wrote a blog post with details and links to both online and browser validators - you can go to my blog and read the post ("Validating Your Web Pages for SEO and Useability - Why You Should Do It and How") if you want more information.

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: I think the W3 Schools validators just send the CSS straight through to Jigsaw for validation.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried validating

`a:after{content:none}`

and it says its valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not validation per se (Firefox doesn't implement all of CSS 2.1), but [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s console tab can show CSS errors. Very handy for developing.

[image]